# Lock acquisition order after notify()

Tags: java, multithreading

Suppose thread T1 is waiting to enter a synchronized block, and thread T2 is `wait()`-ing within the block, and thread T3 calls `notify()` on the block's monitor.

Is it possible for T1 to enter the block before T2 proceeds?  Or does T2 get precedence?

Comment: T2 **can't** be `wait()`-ing *within* the block **and** *on* the block.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: T1 is waiting to enter the block, it hasn't entered it.  T2 is waiting within the block (i.e. at some point in the past it entered the block and called wait() on the monitor).

Comment: Please post some code to clarify. Because I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch - That could have been a typo corrected under the "5 minute rule".  Either way, the question makes sense NOW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible for T1 to enter the block before T2 proceeds?

Yes it is possible.  The javadoc for [`Object.wait(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait--) does not specify that the thread that has been notified takes precedence.  In fact it specifies that *normal* scheduling rules are applied.

> "The thread T is then removed from the wait set for this object and re-enabled for thread scheduling. It then competes in the usual manner with other threads for the right to synchronize on the object ..."

---

This is one of the reasons why you need to code condition variables like this

```
  private boolean condition = ...
  private Object lock = new Object();  // mutex for 'condition'

  ...

  synchronize (lock) {
      while (!condition) {
           wait(lock);
           // It is UNSAFE to assume that 'condition' is true now.
      }
  }
```

Comment: "It then competes in the usual manner with other threads for the right to synchronize on the object" - that's the key bit of information I was missing.  Thanks!